# Why do I keep getting throwing this error? node : internal /modules /cjs/ loader 944 Throw Err ^ (Cannot find module)

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, terminal

> node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:944
> throw err;
> ^
> Error Cannot find module'C:\Coding\git\Mixed-Messages.js

[**Cannot Find Module**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ryj2U.jpg)

Look at Image for source code

Comment: because it is not finding that module - beyond that not sure we can help you decipher your picture really

Comment: Sorry, I am just trying to test a code in VS but when I try running it in the terminal, that's the error I get. Am I suppose to configure Node.js on VS code so that is runs properly?

Comment: try to type and execute command "ls -l" and show us what you get.

Comment: Well, is there any file at "C:\Coding\git\Mixed-messages.js"?

Comment: 'Mixed Messages.js'    README.txt are what are in the directory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

it looks like you are on a different directory (folder).

i suggest you to navigate via "windows explorer" to the where the file "Mixed-Messages.js" is located and then **right click on the file**, **open in cmd**

this should do the trick

### EDIT:

from you last message it looks like the name of the file that you are trying to execute is incorrect.

try running:

```
 node "Mixed Messages.js"
```

or

```
 node Mixed\ Messages.js
```

Free tip:
as best practice you should name the files without spaces.
files should be named:

- Camel Case. ex: mixedMessages.js
- Kebab Case. ex: mixed-messages.js

the 2 above are the most common.

source: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Naming_convention_(programming)#Lisp

Comment: You were right, that was the issue. I didn't input the right file name. Thanks for everyone's help

Comment: I will once I have enough reputation, I am 2 points away.